# How can i force a react component to refresh from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to get a react component to display a list of items that have been retrieved from the backend using websockets. however as my websockets.js file is outside of the react hierarchy the list is never actually refreshed and therefore the items are not displayed.

What i've tried so far is to add a public array of "projects" to the websocketservice.js file and then referencing this list inside my react component. it is however never refreshed even when the websocket returns with its collected values.

**websocketservice.js**

```
class WebSocketService{

projects = []

    static getInstance() {
        if(!WebSocketService.instance){
            WebSocketService.instance = new WebSocketService();
        }
        return WebSocketService.instance;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.socketRef = null;
    }

    connect() {
        const path = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wspingpong/';
        this.socketRef = new WebSocket(path);
        this.socketRef.onopen = () => {
            console.log('websocket opened');
            this.sendTestMessage();
        };

        this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
            console.log("message recieved: " + e.data);
            this.messageRecieved(e.data)
        }

        this.socketRef.onerror = e => {
            console.log(e.onmessage);
        }

        this.socketRef.onclose = () => {
            console.log('websocket is closed');
            this.connect();
        }
    }

    sendMessage(data){
        try{
            this.socketRef.send(JSON.stringify(...data))
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }

    messageRecieved(data) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        const command = parsedData.command;
        if(command === "STC-test"){
            console.log("succesfully recieved a testmessage from the server");
        }
        if(command === "STC-login"){
            console.log("succesfully logged in, redirecting...")
            console.log(parsedData.message)
            this.loggedUser = {
                username: parsedData.message["username"],
                email: parsedData.message["email"]
            }
            history.push("/project")
        }
        if(command === "STC-getprojects"){
            console.log(parsedData.message)
            this.projects = parsedData.message
        }
    }
```

above `console.log(parsedData.message)` correctly shows the list of projects

```
    getProjects(){
        console.log("getting projects....")
        if(this.loggedUser != null){
            var dict = [];
            dict.push({
                command: "CTS-getprojects",
                message: ""
            })
            this.sendMessage(dict)
        }else{
            console.log("no user logged in, unable to retrieve projects.")
        }
    }
```

**ProjectSelect.tsx**

```
export default class ProjectSelect extends React.Component<Iprops>{

    constructor(props: Iprops) {
        super(props)
    }
   render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    WebsocketInstance.loggedUser != null ?
                        <div>
                            <h3>ProjectSelect, welcome user: {WebsocketInstance.loggedUser.username}</h3>
                            {WebsocketInstance.projects.map((name: any) => <span>name: {name}</span>)}
                            <label>Project Name:</label>
                            <input onChange={e => this.setState({ projectname: e.target.value })}></input>
                            <button onClick={() => this.createProject()}>Create a new project</button>

                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                }


            </div>
        )
    }

    createProject() {
        WebsocketInstance.createProject(this.state.projectname)
    }
```

***EDIT***
attempted fix:

```
 constructor(props: Iprops) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            projectnames: []
        }
        this.setState({
            projectnames: WebsocketInstance.projects
        })
}
```

and then inside the render method i added: 
`{this.state.projectnames.map((name: any) => <span>name: {name}</span>)}`

this did however not work

My goal is that as soon as the websocket updates the list with the collected values the react component is refreshed and displays the list of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by giving my websocketinstance a method to callback to:

**projectselect.tsx**

```
constructor(props: Iprops) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            projectnames: [],
            projectname: ""

        }
        WebsocketInstance.callback = this.getProjectsCallback
        WebsocketInstance.getProjects()
    }
    renderMessages = (messages:any) => {
        return messages.map((message:any) => (
            <div>
            <span>{message["projectname"]}</span>
            <button onClick={() => this.openProject(message["id"])}>Load project</button>
            </div>
        ))
    }

    getProjectsCallback = (messages:any) => {
        this.setState({
            projectnames: messages
        })
    }
```

when the callback is called from websocket and is given a new list, i update the state and react will automatically rerender the component.

**websocket.js**

```
messageRecieved(data) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        const command = parsedData.command;
        if(command === "STC-test"){
            console.log("succesfully recieved a testmessage from the server");
        }
        if(command === "STC-login"){
            console.log("succesfully logged in, redirecting...")
            console.log(parsedData.message)
            this.loggedUser = {
                username: parsedData.message["username"],
                email: parsedData.message["email"]
            }
            history.push("/project")
        }
        if(command === "STC-getprojects"){
            console.log(parsedData.message)
            this.callback(parsedData.message)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the return from `WebsocketInstance.createProject(this.state.projectname)` and do something like 
`const myData = WebsocketInstance.createProject(this.state.projectname);
this.setState({webSocitReturn: myData})`

The pattern is to update state/props to have it refresh.  Try to lean into the react API as much as you can to get the desired result.

Also, keep in mind the above code example I put needs some tinkering to account for async.

EDIT: if that does not work, here is a blog post regarding sockets and react. https://blog.logrocket.com/beyond-rest-using-websockets-for-two-way-communication-in-your-react-app-884eff6655f5

Comment: i attempted something simular (dont want createproject to be responsible for updating the list) by settinga array in the state to the websocketinstance.projects var. and calling the state.projectnames in my render method, this however also did not work